# How to remove \n after JSON.stringfy?

Tags: javascript

I parse the data from website and try to change to a json object.

Here is my function:

```
function outPutJSON() {

        for (var i = 0; i < movieTitle.length; i++) {

            var handleN = movieContent[i];
            console.log('===\n');
            console.log(handleN);

            data.movie.push({
                mpvieTitle: movieTitle[i],
                movieEnTitle: movieEnTitle[i],
                theDate: theDate[i],
                theLength: theLength[i],
                movieVersion: movieVersion[i],
                youtubeId: twoId[i],
                content: movieContent[i]
            });
        };

        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
```

console.log will print movieContent[0] like:

[image]

but i return JSON.stringfy(data);
it will become:
[image]

There are so many /n i want to remove it.

I try to change return `JSON.stringfy(data);` to this:

```
var allMovieData = JSON.stringify(data);
allMovieData = allMovieData.replace(/\n/g, '');
return allMovieData;
```

It's not working the result is the same.

How to remove /n when i use `JSON.stringfy()` ?

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `.replace(/\\n/g, '').replace(/\\n/g, '');`? Those might actually not be newline characters.

Comment: Sorry its type error , i fix my question now.

Comment: No, I mean, in  your data screenshots, you literally see `"\n"`. So, try `.replace(/\\n/g, '')` instead of `.replace(/\n/g, '')`.

Comment: Amazing ! It's working . I never thought use  \\n instead of \n , thanks for your reply Cerbrus.

Comment: So, did that work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your data screenshots, you literally *see* `"\n"`.

This probably means that the actual string doesn't contain a newline character (`\n`), but a escaped newline character (`\\n`).

A newline character would have been rendered as a linebreak. You wouldn't see the `\n`.

To remove those, use `.replace(/\\n/g, '')` instead of `.replace(/\n/g, '')`

Answer (score 16):

just :=> 
`JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(<json object>))`

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify` converts new lines (`\n`) and tab (`\t`) chars into string, so, when you will try to parse it, the string will contain those again.

So, you need to search the string `\n`, you can do that with something like that.

```js
const stringWithNewLine = {
  x: `this will conatin 
new lines`
};

const json = JSON.stringify(stringWithNewLine);

console.log(json.replace(/\\n/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it is always good to have options. You can use a string literal as a simple wrapper. The string literal will honor the string's line breaks, empty spaces etc. Like:

```
let jsonAsPrettyString = `${JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2)}`;
```